# how to use FFMpeg in android with easy possible way? with Gradle in android studio for videos concatenation

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am working on video editing in android. After alot of research and
   development the only possible solution for real time video editing
   found is FFMpeg (Other libraries like [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) just impose change
   on video while running instead of changing the video). Want to find
   soltuion where FFMpeg can easily integrate into android studio
   project. Want to do Crop, trim, concatenation and other possible
   process on video.